# Yahoo finance API - get_historical

Tags: python, list, dictionary, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Just got into the yahoo finance API, which i find very useful since web-scraping turned out to be a bit too difficult for me this early into python programming.

Anyway, what i am trying to do is display a monthly high/low for the stock i used the get_historical method on. I realise that what i get is a list of dictionairies (right or wrong?) but i just can't figure out how to fetch the highest/lowest number out of this. The monthly change seems easier, since that would be the first item on the list's price and the last item on the list's price i need. Any ideas? Pretty much just trying to do calculations on the data i pull from get_historical.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
My code for pulling in data. Don't even know where to start in organizing the data that i pull in (using print function for get_historical right now just to be able to see what kind of data i get).

```
import datetime
from yahoo_finance import Share

date_1 = str(datetime.date.today())
date_2 = str(datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=30))


ticker_symbols = ["elx.f", "azn", "eric", "AAPL"]

for i in ticker_symbols:
    stock = Share(i)
    print (stock.get_historical(date_2, date_1))
```

Back to some reading for me now, to see if i can grasp this better by tomorrow! Thankful for any input.

Comment: Please, share some code with us - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Gonna update the main text with my code. Going to do some reading from my book this evening as well but figured i might as well throw out a question while i read and learn more about lists/dicts.